# Remove nans in multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional array. Example (in 2D):

```
x = np.array([[     1.,      1.,  np.nan,  np.nan],
              [     2.,  np.nan,      2.,  np.nan],
              [ np.nan,      3.,  np.nan,  np.nan]])
```

Is there an easy, efficient way to "compress" / "squeeze" / "push" the nans out of it, along an axis? I mean, so that the output (here: axis=0) would become:

```
np.array([[  1.,  1.,  np.nan,  np.nan],
          [  2.,  3.,      2.,  np.nan]])
```

Should also work with more than 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `argsort` on the mask of non-`nan` elements; use a stable sort algorithm (like mergesort) to preserve the original order of the non-`nan` elements:

```
mask = np.isnan(x)
cut = np.min(np.count_nonzero(mask, axis=0))
x[np.argsort(~mask, axis=0, kind='mergesort')[cut:], np.arange(x.shape[1])]
```

Output:

```
array([[  1.,   1.,  nan,  nan],
       [  2.,   3.,   2.,  nan]])
```

ND-version:

```
import numpy as np

def nan_bouncer(x, axis=0):
    if axis != 0:
        x = np.moveaxis(x, axis, 0)
    mask = np.isnan(x)
    cut = np.min(np.count_nonzero(mask, axis=0))
    idx = tuple(np.ogrid[tuple(map(slice, x.shape[1:]))])
    res = x[(np.argsort(~mask, axis=0, kind='mergesort')[cut:],) + idx] 
    return res if axis == 0 else np.moveaxis(res, 0, axis)

#demo
data = np.random.randint(0, 3, (3, 4, 4)).astype(float)
data /= data / data

print(data)
print(nan_bouncer(data))
print(nan_bouncer(data, 2))
```

Sample output:

```
[[[ nan   1.   2.   1.]
  [  2.  nan  nan   2.]
  [  2.   1.   1.   2.]
  [  1.   1.   2.  nan]]

 [[ nan  nan   2.   1.]
  [  2.   2.  nan   1.]
  [  2.   2.   2.   2.]
  [  2.   2.  nan   1.]]

 [[  1.   1.  nan  nan]
  [  1.   1.   2.   1.]
  [  2.  nan   2.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   2.]]]


[[[ nan  nan  nan  nan]
  [  2.  nan  nan   2.]
  [  2.  nan   1.   2.]
  [  1.   1.  nan  nan]]

 [[ nan   1.   2.   1.]
  [  2.   2.  nan   1.]
  [  2.   1.   2.   2.]
  [  2.   2.   2.   1.]]

 [[  1.   1.   2.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   2.   1.]
  [  2.   2.   2.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   2.]]]


[[[ nan   1.   2.   1.]
  [ nan  nan   2.   2.]
  [  2.   1.   1.   2.]
  [ nan   1.   1.   2.]]

 [[ nan  nan   2.   1.]
  [ nan   2.   2.   1.]
  [  2.   2.   2.   2.]
  [ nan   2.   2.   1.]]

 [[ nan  nan   1.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   2.   1.]
  [ nan   2.   2.   1.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   2.]]]
```

Comment: Nice!! How would you do it for more than 2 dimensions?

Comment: @HallgeirWilhelmsen Depends on which rule exactly you want to apply. The easiest generalization would be to keep pushing them out in just one direction. In that case the code would need only minor modifications.

Comment: @HallgeirWilhelmsen I've added an ND version.